# SQL Server : delete row if no constraint error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Much more complicated then this, but this is the basic

- `Person` table (id, name, emailaddress)
- `Salesperson` table (id, personID)
- `CustomerServiceRep` table (id, personID)

Jeff is salesperson (id=4) and customerservicerep (id=5) with personID=1.

Simple

```
Trigger on SalesPerson Table 
AFTER DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @personID int = (SELECT personID FROM deleted);

    IF @personID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN TRY
         DELETE FROM Person 
         WHERE Person.id = @personID;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH

DELETE FROM SalesPerson WHERE id=4;
```

Causes

> Msg 3616, Level 16, State 1
>   An error was raised during trigger execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if any, has been rolled back.

I'm sure there's a much simpler way to not delete `personID` if it exists from some kind of constraint. Or catch the constraint. To go through every possible table that this could be in seems very repetitive and potentially more difficult when there are more tables/columns that may use this same table/constraint (foreign key).

Answer (score 0):

You need an instead of delete trigger here rather than an after trigger.

```
CREATE Trigger tr_Delete_person 
on Person 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Delete any child records 

    Delete FROM SalesPerson 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted 
                  WHERE personID = SalesPerson.personID)


    Delete FROM CustomerServiceRep  
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted 
                  WHERE personID = CustomerServiceRep .personID)


-- Finally delete from the person table 
    DELETE FROM Person 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted 
                  WHERE personID = Person .personID)


END
```

Comment: That seems like it will get rid of everything related to the person "jeff".  Only wanting to remove salesperson "jeff", not customerservicerep "jeff" and if the person "jeff" is still existing because "jeff" is a customerservicerep also, don't delete person.  I feel like there should be a complete easier way to do this without adding every table that could possibly have personID to check if it exists there before deleting person "jeff"

Comment: @user2828970, I'd set up a foreign key between `Person` and `SalesPerson` with cascade delete. And a foreign key between `Person` and `CustomerServiceRep` with no cascade. If there are more tables that reference `Person` you need to set up foreign keys with appropriate cascade action for all of them as well.

Comment: I see how that can be useful.  Cascade is a new thing for me.  Looking at it though, I haven't yet seen how to make it not delete the person if it exists in a different table.  The tables SalesPerson And CustomerServiceRep are basically equal (no priority over each).  "jeff" can be removed from customerServiceRep just like removed from SalesPerson but if still existing somewhere, the person should not be deleted.  Obviously with long lines of code this can be checked.

Comment: But I'm looking for the easy simple way to do this without having to constantly go back and modify the code when a new table pointing to the same person constraint is created.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a fundamental flaw in your trigger in that you seem to expect that the trigger will be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo table `Deleted` might contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
DECLARE @personID int = (SELECT personID FROM deleted);
```

It's undefined - you'll get the value from **one, arbitrary row** in `Deleted`, and all others are ignored - typically **not** what you want!

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge the `Deleted` **WILL** contain multiple rows! You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Deleted` !